# Jsoup parsing, 400 error

Tags: parsing, jsoup

I am writing a program that goes to a web page, finds and downloads all images and common documents (.docx .pdf etc.) and then visits each link on the pages and does the same. The problem I'm running into is when I get deep into parsing links I am getting 400 errors with jsoup:
`Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400, URL=http://www.somerandomurl.com`

Code:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlstring).userAgent("Chrome").get();
```

Help?

Answer (score 0):

How do you parse the link (some more code please)? Often its necessary to use an absolut link instead of the simple  attribute.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a problem with accents or special characters that might be in your url.